# Next image size increased after deployment

Tags: image, next.js

Image sizes are increased after deployment. I have seen the image while running in local the size was - 17.4KB URL- http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.graphassets.com%2FdJewd5dhQ1aqkxjkEw71&w=1920&q=100
[image]

After deployment that same image size changed to - 54.7KB URL- https://stage.accuride.com/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.graphassets.com%2FdJewd5dhQ1aqkxjkEw71&w=1920&q=100
[image]

Can anyone specify the reason for that?

- Next.js version - 12.3.4
- Deployment done with next serverless in AWS lamda using @sls-next/serverless-component@3.5.3-alpha.4.